# Something wrong with parallel task execution along with Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I tried the following in a console application.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Console.WriteLine("Main");

    var task1 = Method1(sw);
    var task2 = Method2(sw);

    await task1;
    await task2;
    //await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2); // results in the same behavior
}

static Task<bool> Method1(Stopwatch sw)
{
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Console.WriteLine("Method1 " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    return Task.FromResult(true);
}

static Task<bool> Method2(Stopwatch sw)
{
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Console.WriteLine("Method2 " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    return Task.FromResult(false);
}
```

I expected `Method1` and `Method2` to run in parallel and print something like

```
Main
Method1 3047
Method2 3052
```

But the actual output came as

```
Main
Method1 3047
Method2 6052
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Task != Thread. Method1 and Method2 do not contain any `await` so in fact  both are executed synchronously. Did you mean `await Task.Delay(3000)`?

Comment: Yes, `await Task.Delay(3000)` worked. Thank you!